# Does linux support Intel DVMT?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, games, intel, gpu

Does Linux (Ubuntu in particular) support [Intel DVMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_video_memory_technology)?

I've Intel i5-2500K, 8GB RAM with NO graphics card. It has inbuilt 32MB dedicated graphics memory.

In my Windows OS, graphics memory is dynamically allocated from RAM (which goes up-to 1.7GB) and most of the games works fairly well at low FPS. As Ubuntu is in a way to become a gaming platform, I would like to know weather Intel DVMT is supported.

Comment: Related question on Intel forums: [Using DVMT to distribute system memory to HD2000 Integrated graphics processor](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/292420)

Comment: @gertvdijk - Unfortunately that question does not have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about actual support, but if the question is whether memory is allocated to the graphics, then at least on my laptop with Intel i3 processor and HD4000 graphics that does happen.

On Ubuntu 12.10 and 1.8 GiB of my total RAM is always reserved for the graphics (unfortunately leaving only 2.1 GiB of memory to use). I have not seen any sign of it changing dynamically, ever.

The behaviour on Ubuntu seems to match the behaviour on Windows 7 (on Windows 7, the Resource Monitor reports 1853 MB of being "Hardware Reserved").

My laptop BIOS does not have settings related to this, so I have no control over this. Personally I would like to allocate less memory to the graphics, since currently it only leaves 2.1 GiB to use.

Comment: Does it have settings for Video memory?

Comment: No, BIOS has no settings related to this. This might be just my laptop's thing (Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E330, BIOS is up-to-date).

Comment: Indeed, not all OEMs allow modification of such settings. If there's not option in the BIOS this can't be modified.

Comment: @pileofrocks - How to see amount of memory reserved for graphics?

Comment: @NikhilDamle For me this is shown as kernel messages, e.g. `dmesg | grep intel.*map`.

Comment: @gertvdijk - No signs of graphics memory in kernel messages in my KUbuntu 12.10 :(

Comment: @NikhilDamle - I have not found a way to see the reserved memory in Ubuntu. As I said, I got the exact figure (1853 MB) from Windows' Resource Monitor. The command by gertvdijk doesn't show me anything either.